# How to get comparison of variable in lists as objects of class contained in another list?

Tags: c#, list, listview, comparison

Class contained in list:

```
List<Artists> TopArtistsByTags = new List<Artists>();
```

That class:

```
public class Artists
{
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags;
}
```

I hope to get all `ArtistName` by comparison of matching duplicates of items in `List<string> Tags` (Maybe with this items as class? So i'm going to add them both as items and subitems to `listView`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
List<Artists> artists = //the list of artists
var tags = artists.SelectMany(x => x.Tags).Distinct();
foreach (var tag in tags)
{
    var artistsWithThisTag = artists.Where(x => x.Tags.Contains(tag));
    //do something with artistsWithThisTag
}
```

The performance of this could surely be improved, but you should only concern yourself with that if you find it is a problem.

Comment: It looks like what I need, but doesn't work. Maybe it `Distinct()` was the reason?

Comment: can u throw some light on how to optimize this? any references or resources would be helpful

Comment: @alok I would probably loop through the Artists and build a dictionary with tags as keys and lists of artists as values. That should be fairly quick to build, and then easy to look up/use. Hope this helps give you a direction to go!

Comment: good for the current example, my question was more generic. about optimizing linq queries!

Comment: @Alok more generically, for LINQ to objects, make use of ToDictionary or ToLookup where possible. That can help performance dramatically in a variety of situations. I don't have enough familiarity with LINQ querying databases to speak to that.